# IndexError while scraping from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have been trying to scrape data from xhamster  channels  for my research using this code

```
import json
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

from lxml import html

from util import req


def get_channel_urls(url):
    r = req(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
    print("Done", url)
    return [x.attrib['href'] for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="item"]/a')]

def write_channel_data(url):
    r = req(url)
    html_text = r.text
    tree = html.fromstring(html_text)
    json_data = json.loads(
        tree.xpath('//script[@id="initials-script"]/text()')[0].strip().split("window.initials =")[1][:-1].strip())
    with open("channel_html/{}".format(json_data['sponsorChannel']['inurl']), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(html_text)
    print("Written data for:", url)


def main():
    letters = '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz'
    index_urls = ['https://xhamster.com/channels/all/{}'.format(index_letter) for index_letter in letters]
    index_urls.extend(['https://xhamster.com/gay/channels/all/{}'.format(index_letter) for index_letter in letters])
    index_urls.extend(['https://xhamster.com/shemale/channels/all/{}'.format(index_letter) for index_letter in letters])
    channel_urls = []
    for url in index_urls:
        channel_urls.extend(get_channel_urls(url))

    with open('channel_urls', 'w') as channel_url_backup_file:
        channel_url_backup_file.write("\n".join(channel_urls))

    # with open('channel_urls') as i:  # THIS IS TO READ A PRE-DOWNLOADED URL FILE
    #     channel_urls = [url.strip() for url in i.read().split()]

    with ThreadPool(processes=10) as pool:
        pool.map(write_channel_data, channel_urls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It does work for a while but  then i get this error. The error is obviously in the main() funtion but I cant figure how to solve it
[IndexError: list out of index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rp2D.png)

Comment: You're getting an `IndexError` when defining `json_data` in the `write_channel_data` function. I suspect it's from `...split("window.initials =")[1]` since it won't split if that text is not found. You should spend some more time examining the contents of the html `tree` to figure out why certain `channel_urls` don't have the text "windows.initials = "

Comment: It's shown that you encounter error at line `tree.xpath('//script[@id="initials-script"]/text()')....`. Try breakdown that line into multiple shorter line to detect which part of that line have error and update the question if you still cant fix it.